# Sharing javascript files in separate project

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I want to share my validation javascript in my framework project with my normal website.

I have a project folder called framework, this is where I define core functionality and validation in a form of attributes.

The problem is this framework project also includes javascript files for client side validation. I want to reference these files in my main project. How would I go about the correct way of doing this?

I know about setting the build action to set the file in the bin folder and reference file within the bin. But I read this is the incorrect way of going about it. I am using visual studio 2012 with an mvc 4.5 project.

Comment: how about this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234

Comment: Ok thats great. But the article does not say how I can reference the file in my view.

Comment: you can do a folder with set of links in the project(where you have the view), after that just reference to scripts from that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I share common resources (css/javascript etc) among projects by using nuget packages.

These are the steps I take.

**Create nuget package**

First create a nuget package that contains the javascript files.

I used Scott Hanselman's blog here to do that here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx

**Store the new package on a network share**

Drop the nuget package onto a network share which can be used as a package source repository.

**Add to Visual Studio**

Then add the package source repository into visual studio that points to your network share (Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > Package Sources > Add)

**Add/Update in other projects**

In each project you wish to use it you can just run the `Install-Package` to install and `Update-Package` to update.